# Basic Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, exponential-function

[image]

Is this first linear ODE? I'm quite confused because the y is in the position of exponential of e.

Comment: or perhaps a separable ODE?

Comment: yes, it's a separable ODE.

Comment: but it is not linear.